# Como posso definir a minha variável "u"?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Está aparecendo o seguinte erro: **Notice: Undefined variable: u in C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\mensagens\cadastrar.php on line 30 Fatal error: Call to a member function conectar() on a non-object in C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\mensagens\cadastrar.php on line 30**

Tentei de alguns modos resolver o problema, mas não está funcionando, como posso resolver?

```
<html lang="pt-br" >
  <head>
  <title>Projeto Login</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="corp-form" >
    <form method="POST" >
      <h1>Cadastrar</h1>
      <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" maxlength="30" />
      <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Usuário" maxlength="30" />
      <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" maxlength="16" />
      <input type="password" name="confSenha" placeholder="Confirmar a senha" maxlength="16" />
      <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
    </form>
    </div>
    <?php
    date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
    if(isset($_POST['nome']))
    {
      $nome = $_POST['nome'];
      $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
      $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
      $confirmarSenha = addslashes($_POST['confSenha']);
      //verificar se esta preenchido
      if(!empty($nome) && !empty($email) && !empty($senha)
      && !empty($confirmarSenha))
      {
        $u->conectar("projeto_login","localhost","root","");
        if($nome->msgErro == "")
        {
          if($senha == $confirmarSenha)
        {
        if($u->cadastrar($nome,$email,$senha))
        {
            echo "Cadastrado com sucesso! Acesse para entrar.";
          }
          else
          {
              echo "Email já cadastrado!";
          }
        }
        else
        {
          echo "Senha e confirmar senha não correspondem!";
        }
      }
      else
      {
          echo "Erro: ".$u->msgErro;
        }
      }else
      {
          echo "Preencha todos os campos!";

    }
  }
     ?>
  </body>
</html>
```

Pelo que entendi a minha variável "u" não está definida, já defini de outros modos, mas não funcionou.

Comment: aonde você declarou o "u", não vejo nenhum include de outro arquivo e nem a declaração dela

Comment: Junto com essa parte **$nome = $_POST['nome'];
      $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
      $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
      $confirmarSenha = addslashes($_POST['confSenha']);** Declarei ela como um conjunto de todas essas, mas falhou. Ela não declarei nesse código pois aparentemente não estou sabendo declarar ela corretamente.

Comment: Não possui nenhuma declaração de variável ```$u``` no seu código. Ela está em algum arquivo externo?

Comment: @JoãoVitor Eu defini ela no meu index.php **<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  require_once 'CLASSES/usuarios.php';
  $u = new Usuario;
 ?>
<html lang="pt-br" >
  <head>
  <title>Projeto Login</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />
  </head>**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<?php
//...
require_once 'CLASSES/Usuario.php';
$u = new Usuario();
//...
?>
<html>
...
</html>
```

Verifique se na classe Usuario.php está realmente com `class name Usuario{...`

Comment: Fiz isso e descobri mais erros no meu usuarios.php `Notice: Use of undefined constant name - assumed 'name' in C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\mensagens\CLASSES\usuarios.php on line 13 Warning: PDO::__construct(): [2002] Nenhuma conex�o p�de ser feita porque a m�quina de destino as recusou ativamente. (trying to connect via tcp://localhost:3306) in C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\mensagens\CLASSES\usuarios.php on line 13 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in C:\WebServer\Apache2.2\htdocs\mensagens\CLASSES\usuarios.php on line 13 Notice: Trying to get property of non-object in`

Comment: Mas, obrigado, aparentemente solucionou o meu atual.

Comment: A conexão com banco de dados não está funcionando portanto não está conseguindo criar o objeto, tente sempre proteger seu código com if(isset()) ou is_null, ou algo do tipo quando há consulta no banco de dados e há possibilidade do registro não existir, erros de conexão ou indisponibilidade do bd.

Answer (score 1):

Ao que parece você não incluiu a classe, consequentemente não instanciou a mesma.
Tente o seguinte:

```
<?php
     require('diretório/da/classe.php');
     u = new Classe;
  ?>    
  <html lang="pt-br" >
      <head>
      <title>Projeto Login</title>
      <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <div id="corp-form" >
        <form method="POST" >
          <h1>Cadastrar</h1>
          <input type="text" name="nome" placeholder="Nome completo" maxlength="30" />
          <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="Usuário" maxlength="30" />
          <input type="password" name="senha" placeholder="Senha" maxlength="16" />
          <input type="password" name="confSenha" placeholder="Confirmar a senha" maxlength="16" />
          <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Cadastrar" />
        </form>
        </div>
        <?php
        date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
        if(isset($_POST['nome']))
        {
          $nome = $_POST['nome'];
          $email = addslashes($_POST['email']);
          $senha = addslashes($_POST['senha']);
          $confirmarSenha = addslashes($_POST['confSenha']);
          //verificar se esta preenchido
          if(!empty($nome) && !empty($email) && !empty($senha)
          && !empty($confirmarSenha))
          {
            $u->conectar("projeto_login","localhost","root","");
            if($nome->msgErro == "")
            {
              if($senha == $confirmarSenha)
            {
            if($u->cadastrar($nome,$email,$senha))
            {
                echo "Cadastrado com sucesso! Acesse para entrar.";
              }
              else
              {
                  echo "Email já cadastrado!";
              }
            }
            else
            {
              echo "Senha e confirmar senha não correspondem!";
            }
          }
          else
          {
              echo "Erro: ".$u->msgErro;
            }
          }else
          {
              echo "Preencha todos os campos!";

        }
      }
         ?>
      </body>
    </html>
```

Assim você poderá acessar os objetos da classe.
Teste isso e diga o que retornou.

A propósito, você pode trocar o require() por include().

Comment: A minha variável "u" está definida em index.php `<?php
date_default_timezone_set('America/Sao_Paulo');
  require_once 'CLASSES/usuarios.php';
  $u = new Usuario;
 ?>
<html lang="pt-br" >
  <head>
  <title>Projeto Login</title>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/login.css" />
  </head>` Quando dou include ou require, ele junta as duas páginas e a tela de login e cadastrar ficam uma em cima da outra.